# typeof 90/'hi' is NaN while typeof (90/'hi') is number. Why so?

Tags: javascript, nan

I was playing around the NaN of JavaScript and found some strange behavior while using typeof operator on a result of number/string.
why so?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Where do you see `parseInt()` being used here?

Comment: My bad, I went one step ahead.. will explain below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeof 90/"hi"` is executed as `(typeof 90)/"hi"` which becomes `"number"/"hi"` => `NaN`

`typeof (90/"hi")` => `typeof NaN` => `"number"`

Answer (score 3):

```
typeof NaN === 'number'; // Despite being "Not-A-Number"
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

And the precedence of typeof is higher than `/`, so you are evaluating `(typeof '90')/'hi'`, which is `NaN`

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Thanks @Otto for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Priority is the answer here:

`typeof 90/'hi'` becomes `'number'/'hi'` that's because `typeof 90` is 'number' which gives `NaN` as final result

You can check the priority table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that when you write typeof `90/'hi'` it first gets the type of 90 (number) and then divides it by 'hi' which produces the NaN. Basically it's equal to `'number'/'hi'`. 
When you include 90/'hi' in brackets it first gets the NaN from the division of number (90) by string 'hi' and then gets the type of NaN, which is 'number'.